# Elastic beanstalk not displaying Web Application

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, iis-7.5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just started using Amazon Web services, and I am trying to deploy a Web application using elastic beanstalk from visual studio.  Every time I deploy it and go to the URL all I see is the IIS 7 logo and nothing else.  How do I get my application to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like to you need to navigate to whatever you set as your start page. Something like,

www.mysite.com/Default.aspx

If you haven't set up a start page you can right click on your default aspx page in Visual Studio and select "Set as Start Page".

If this still doesn't work I recommend you RDP into your instance, open IIS, and make sure your site files are actually being deployed to the server.